# ArangoDB out of memory exception

Tags: out-of-memory, arangodb

I have two edge collections: `edges_temp` with 17 millions edges and `myedges` with 22 millions edges
I'm doing the following:

```
FOR edge IN edges_temp
UPSERT { _key:edges_temp._key } 
INSERT { _from: edge._from, _to: edge._to, coccurrence: edge.coccurrence, _key:edges_temp._key } 
UPDATE { coccurrence: OLD.coccurrence + edge.coccurrence } 
IN myedges
```

And getting the error

> Query: AQL: out of memory (exception location:
>   C:\b\workspace\RELEASE__BuildPackages\lib\V8\v8-vpack.cpp:125)
>   stacktrace of offending AQL function: ArangoError: out of memory
>   (exception location:
>   C:\b\workspace\RELEASE__BuildPackages\lib\V8\v8-vpack.cpp:125) at
>   Object.GET_DOCUMENTS (c:\Program Files\ArangoDB3
>   3.3.4\usr\share\arangodb3\js\server\modules\@arangodb\aql.js:1182:39) at Function. (--script--:1:183) (exception location:
>   C:\b\workspace\RELEASE__BuildPackages\arangod\Aql\V8Executor.cpp:333)
>   (while executing) (exception location:
>   C:\b\workspace\RELEASE__BuildPackages\arangod\RestHandler\RestCursorHandler.cpp:134)

I understand that they are quite a big collections which are loaded in RAM, but at the moment I get the error I have ~4GB free RAM.
What else could cause that exception?

UPD:

OS: win10

ArangoDB v.3.3.4

All settings were by default, storage engine: auto, single machine.

Comment: Please add operating system, ArangoDB version and configuration settings (e.g. is it single instance, cluster, storage engine...)

Comment: In any case, I would suggest to carry the issue to https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues